# XDS510PP-PLUS JTAG Emulator on windows 7

Tags: programming, ezdsp, ti-ccstudio

I'm trying to use a spectrum digital XDS510PP parallel port to jtag emulator to program an ezdsp board. It's not working and I don't see any problem except that it only supports up windows XP. Is it possible that it just can't work with windows 7? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's an old unit, and would need to have a driver written for Windows 7. Very few, if any, systems running Windows 7 will even have a parallel port. The cheapest solution would be to use a Win XP system.